# Parsing issues with resume written in LaTeX

Tags: formatting, parsing

I've written my resume in Overleaf and downloaded it as a PDF to submit to job applications.

For some job applications it works but for others I'm told there is a parsing error (i.e. their automated system can't extract the info from my resume).

I was told by my professors that writing a resume in LaTeX not only looks good but is generally standard for science and engineering jobs.

I'm being told by one recruiter that my resume has "too much formatting" as a pdf image file and to convert it to a text or word document (which ruins all my work).

**What is the best method to write something in LaTeX and then convert it to a form these online application sites can read?**

I put a lot of work into my resume and it looks very nice... I don't want to change its appearance.

Answer (score 0):

Use these two lines in your preamble:

```
\input{glyphtounicode}

\pdfgentounicode=1
```

Also check for their website sometimes the parsers mention that they will work better with .doc or .docx file

Comment: Yeah, I just saw this solution on Reddit. I'll try to verify if it works. Thank you

Comment: so far this preamble is not working. I did notice that using Adobe Pro to convert the PDF into an editable/searchable document worked although the info is quite mangled and inaccurate once it's uploaded but at least it's not being rejected

Comment: Do you have any language specific special characters ?

Comment: As in a human language? No. The company used another company called "Dayforce" and Dayforce does mention that .doc files work with their parser... aaaand I just noticed you can convert a PDF into a .doc file very easily and the appearance isn't changed so maybe I will stick with that from now on when submitting a resume since as a .doc file, the resume is made of text instead of "images" like my PDF is

Comment: I can't comment on the situation without seeing the code maybe some packages are clashing or changing the behaviour of text to image